# Email service that can limit number of times I can check my emails?

Tags: webapp-rec, email

I constantly waste time checking email jokes and so that people send me, so I created an email account only for friends, leaving the existing one for work only. Yet I still spend too much time checking the friends' account.

Is there an email webapp that can be configured to only let me check my email once per week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a service that will do this.

Are you *really* convinced that you're spending too much time on your play email account?  If so don't you think you would have stopped?  You should use an Internet usage monitoring program so you can see for yourself how much time you're really wasting there.  Perhaps the shock will give you the self discipline you need!

Ultimately it is self discipline you'll need since if you really want to you can bypass any limitations you attempt to impose on yourself.

Of course if you're wasting time at work, you can approach your system admins and explain the problem you're having to them and see if they can block the problem sites for you.  Sure, if you really wanted to you can get around this too, but maybe knowing that other people (at work, no less) know you have your problem you'll be able to control yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-on for the Firefox web browser called [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476/) that limits your time by website. If you use a different webmail provider, you could use that to stop from spending too much time on the other account.